# How to make a Zoom Control on WebView?

Tags: android, webview, zooming, pinchzoom

Good day.

I'm new @android programming.
I use Eclipse.
My question is, I've seen Zoom Control on left panel in layout. then I try to drag it (ZoomControl) to the layout. then I run my project.
it shows the zoom control but I can't zoom in and zoom out the text on my webview. anyone can help me please ?

how to call it ? how to implement it ?
I use webview for learning application, and it need zoom control to zoom in and zoom out the text on it.

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try code below:

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: thank you very much @young_boy.
I'll try your suggestion. but, it is placed on the class right ? on the WebViewAct.java ? is'n it ?

Comment: You can put this code into Activity contain Webview ``mWebview`` is instance of Webview match from layout ``findbyId``.

Besides another way: If ``WebViewAct.java`` is class ``extend`` from ``WebView`` you can put code like : ``    this.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    this.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    this.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    this.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);`` in contructor  method of this class.
Sorry, my EngLish is not good